# MATLAB Figure file

Tags: matlab, matrix, matlab-figure, contour, gaussian

I have a problem with contour figure, when I run my syntax I get error like:

```
Error using contourf (line 66)
Z must be size 2x2 or greater.

Error in example (line 660)
    contourf (x,y,c); colorbar;
```

and this is my syntax:

```
%---------------------stack1--------------------------------------------

v = 0.5;                    % velocity

lambda = 0;                 % decay rate

Q = 1;                      % emission rate(s)

u = 3;                      % wind speed

P = 1;                      % Ambient Pressure

D = 6;                      % inside diameter

V = 22.4;                   % volumetric flow rate of stack gas

Ts = 400;                   % temperature of stack gas  

Ta = 283;                   % temperature of ambient air  

xstack = 0; ystack = 60;    % stack location(s)

xmin = 0.5; xmax = 3.5;     % x-axis interval

ymin = 0; ymax = 100;       % y-axis interval (used only for d>1))

h = 50;                     % physical stack height

z = 0;                      % height of observation (=0 for ground surface)

gplot = 1;                  % plot option (=1 yes; =0 no)

gcont = 2;                  % contour plot option (=2 filled; =1 yes; =0 none) 

%----------------------------------execution-------------------------------

[x,y] = meshgrid (linspace(xmin,xmax,100),linspace(ymin,ymax,100));

c = zeros (size(x)); e = ones(size(x));

Dy = linspace(1,100,100); %  in meters

Dz = Dy'; %  in meters

[Dy,Dz] = meshgrid(Dz,Dy);

for i=1:100

   for j=1:100

   %...Pasquill-gifford for Dy

      c = 24.167; d = 2.5334;%...Pasquill Stability Category is A

      if x(i,j)<0.10; % x in kilometers

         th = 0.017453293.*(c - d.*log(x(i,j)));

         Dy(i,j) = 465.11628.*x(i,j).*(tan(th));

      end

   c = 18.3330; d = 1.8096;%...Pasquill Stability Category is B

   if x(i,j)<0.20 % x in kilometers

      th = 0.017453293.*(c - d.*log(x(i,j)));

      Dy(i,j) = 465.11628.*x(i,j).*(tan(th)); 

   end


   c = 12.5000; d = 1.0857;%...Pasquill Stability Category is C

   if x(i,j) == 4; % x in kilometers 

      th = 0.017453293.*(c - d.*log(x(i,j)));

      Dy(i,j) = 465.11628.*x(i,j).*(tan(th)); 

   end

   c = 8.3330; d = 0.72382;%...Pasquill Stability Category is D

   if x(i,j)== 0.30 % x in kilometers

      th = 0.017453293.*(c - d.*log(x(i,j)));

      Dy(i,j) = 465.11628.*x(i,j).*(tan(th)); 

   end


   c = 6.2500; d = 0.54287; %...Pasquill Stability Category is E

   if x(i,j) < 0.10 % x in kilometers 

      th = 0.017453293.*(c - d.*log(x(i,j)));

      Dy(i,j) = 465.11628.*x(i,j).*(tan(th)); 

   end


   c = 4.1667; d = 0.36191; %...Pasquill Stability Category is F

   if x(i,j) < 0.20 % x in kilometers

      th = 0.017453293.*(c - d.*log(x(i,j)));

      Dy(i,j) = 465.11628.*x(i,j).*(tan(th));

   end


%...Pasquill-gifford for Dz


   if x(i,j)<0.10 % x in kilometers

      a = 122.8; b = 0.9447;%...stabilitas is A

      Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b; 



      if Dz(i,j)>5000

         Dz(i,j)=5000;

      end

   elseif 0.100 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 0.150

      a = 158.08; b = 1.0542;

      Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;


      if Dz(i,j)>5000

         Dz(i,j)=5000;

      end

   elseif 0.150 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 0.200

      a= 170.22 ; b= 1.0932 ;

      Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;


      if Dz(i,j)>5000

         Dz(i,j)=5000;

      end

   elseif 0.200 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 0.250

      a= 179.52 ; b= 1.1262 ;

      Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;


      if Dz(i,j)>5000

         Dz(i,j)=5000;

      end

   elseif 0.250 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 0.300

      a= 217.41 ; b= 1.2644 ;

      Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;


      if Dz(i,j)>5000

         Dz(i,j)=5000;

      end

   elseif 0.300 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 0.400

a= 258.89 ; b= 1.4094 ;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b; 


if Dz(i,j)>5000

Dz(i,j)=5000;

end

elseif 0.400 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 0.500

a= 346.75 ; b= 1.7283 ;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;


if Dz(i,j)>5000

Dz(i,j)=5000;

end

elseif 0.500 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 3.110

a= 453.85 ; b= 2.1166 ;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;


if Dz(i,j)>5000

Dz(i,j)=5000;

end

elseif x(i,j) >= 3.110

a= 453.85 ; b= 2.1166 ;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  


if Dz(i,j)>5000

Dz(i,j)=5000;

end

if x(i,j)<0.20 % x in kilometers

a = 90.673; b = 0.93198;%...stabilitas is B

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end


if Dz(i,j)>5000

Dz(i,j)=5000;

end

elseif 0.21 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 0.40

a = 98.483; b = 0.98332;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b; 


if Dz(i,j)>5000

Dz = 5000;

end

elseif x(i,j)>= 0.40

a = 109.400; b = 1.09710;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

if Dz(i,j)>5000

Dz = 5000;

end



if x(i,j) == all % x in kilometers

a = 61.141; b = 0.91465;%...stabilitas is C

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  


if Dz(i,j)>5000

Dz = 5000;

end





if x(i,j)== 0.30 % x in kilometers

a = 34.459; b = 0.86974;%...stabilitas is D

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end


if 0.31 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 1.00

a = 32.093; b = 0.81066;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end


if 1.01 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 3.00

a = 32.093; b = 0.64403;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end


if 3.01 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 10.00

a = 33.504; b = 0.60486;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end

if 10.01 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 30.00

a = 36.650; b = 0.56589;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end

if x(i,j)>= 30.00

a = 44.053; b =0.51179;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end



if x(i,j) < 0.10 % x in kilometers

a = 24.260; b = 0.83660; %...stabilitas is E  

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b; 

end


if 0.10 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 30.00

a = 23.331; b = 0.81956;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end


if 0.31 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 1.00

a = 21.628; b = 0.75660;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end


if 1.01 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 2.00

a = 21.628; b = 0.63077;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end

if 2.01 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 4.00

a = 22.534; b = 0.57154;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end

if 4.01 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 10.00

a = 24.703; b = 0.50527;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end

if 10.01 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 20.00

a = 26.970; b = 0.46713;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end

if 20.01 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 40.00

a = 35.420; b = 0.37615;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end

if x(i,j) >=40.00

a = 44.053; b = 0.51179;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end


if x(i,j) < 0.20 % x in kilometers

a = 15.209; b = 0.81558;%...stabilitas is F

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end

if 0.21 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 0.70

a = 14.457; b = 0.78407;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b; 

end

if 0.71 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 1.00

a = 13.953; b = 0.68465;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b; 

end

if 1.01 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 2.00

a = 13.953; b = 0.63227;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b; 

end

if 2.01 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 3.00

a = 14.823; b = 0.54503;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end

if 3.01 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 7.00

a = 16.187; b = 0.46490;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end

if 7.01 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 15.00

a = 17.836; b = 0.41507;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end


if 15.01 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 30.00

a = 22.651; b = 0.32681;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end

if 30.01 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 60.00

a = 27.074; b = 0.27436;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end


if x(i,j)>= 60.00

a = 34.219; b = 0.21716;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;

end

end

end


end

end

for i = 1:size(Q,2)

    xx = x - xstack(i);

    yy = y - ystack(i); 

end


    deltah(i,j) = V.*D./u.*1.5 + 2.68.*(10^(-3)).*P.*(Ts-Ta).*D./Ts;

    H = h + deltah;

 c1 = c + Q(i).*e./(4.*pi.*xx.*sqrt(Dy.*Dz)).*exp(-v.*yy.*yy./(4.*Dy.*xx)).*... 

(exp(-v.*(z-H(i)).*(z-H(i)).*e./(4.*Dz.*xx))+exp(-v.*(z+H(i)).*(z+H(i)).*e./(4.*Dz.*xx)))...

.*exp(-lambda.*xx./v);

%--------------------------stack2---------------------------------------------

v = 0.5;                    % velocity

lambda = 0;                 % decay rate

Q = 1;                      % emission rate(s)

u = 3;                      % wind speed

P = 1;                      % Ambient Pressure

D = 6;                      % inside diameter

V = 22.4;                   % volumetric flow rate of stack gas

Ts = 400;                   % temperature of stack gas  

Ta = 283;                   % temperature of ambient air  

xstack = 0; ystack = 40;    % stack location(s)

xmin = 0.5; xmax = 3.5;     % x-axis interval

ymin = 0; ymax = 100;       % y-axis interval (used only for d>1))

h = 50;                     % physical stack height

z = 0;                      % height of observation (=0 for ground surface)

gplot = 1;                  % plot option (=1 yes; =0 no)

gcont = 2;                  % contour plot option (=2 filled; =1 yes; =0 none) 

%----------------------------------execution-------------------------------

[x,y] = meshgrid (linspace(xmin,xmax,100),linspace(ymin,ymax,100));

c = zeros (size(x)); e = ones(size(x));

Dy = linspace(1,100,100); %  in meters

Dz = Dy'; %  in meters

[Dy,Dz] = meshgrid(Dz,Dy);

for i=1:100

for j=1:100

%...Pasquill-gifford for Dy

c = 24.167; d = 2.5334;%...Pasquill Stability Category is A

if x(i,j)<0.10; % x in kilometers

th = 0.017453293.*(c - d.*log(x(i,j)));

Dy(i,j) = 465.11628.*x(i,j).*(tan(th));

end

c = 18.3330; d = 1.8096;%...Pasquill Stability Category is B

if x(i,j)<0.20 % x in kilometers

th = 0.017453293.*(c - d.*log(x(i,j)));

Dy(i,j) = 465.11628.*x(i,j).*(tan(th)); 

end


c = 12.5000; d = 1.0857;%...Pasquill Stability Category is C

if x(i,j) == 4; % x in kilometers 

th = 0.017453293.*(c - d.*log(x(i,j)));

Dy(i,j) = 465.11628.*x(i,j).*(tan(th)); 

end

c = 8.3330; d = 0.72382;%...Pasquill Stability Category is D

if x(i,j)== 0.30 % x in kilometers

th = 0.017453293.*(c - d.*log(x(i,j)));

Dy(i,j) = 465.11628.*x(i,j).*(tan(th)); 

end


c = 6.2500; d = 0.54287; %...Pasquill Stability Category is E

if x(i,j) < 0.10 % x in kilometers 

th = 0.017453293.*(c - d.*log(x(i,j)));

Dy(i,j) = 465.11628.*x(i,j).*(tan(th)); 

end


c = 4.1667; d = 0.36191; %...Pasquill Stability Category is F

if x(i,j) < 0.20 % x in kilometers

th = 0.017453293.*(c - d.*log(x(i,j)));

Dy(i,j) = 465.11628.*x(i,j).*(tan(th));

end


%...Pasquill-gifford for Dz


if x(i,j)<0.10 % x in kilometers

a = 122.8; b = 0.9447;%...stabilitas is A

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b; 



if Dz(i,j)>5000

Dz(i,j)=5000;

end

elseif 0.100 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 0.150

a = 158.08; b = 1.0542;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;


if Dz(i,j)>5000

Dz(i,j)=5000;

end

elseif 0.150 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 0.200

a= 170.22 ; b= 1.0932 ;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;


if Dz(i,j)>5000

Dz(i,j)=5000;

end

elseif 0.200 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 0.250

a= 179.52 ; b= 1.1262 ;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;


if Dz(i,j)>5000

Dz(i,j)=5000;

end

elseif 0.250 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 0.300

a= 217.41 ; b= 1.2644 ;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;


if Dz(i,j)>5000

Dz(i,j)=5000;

end

elseif 0.300 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 0.400

a= 258.89 ; b= 1.4094 ;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b; 


if Dz(i,j)>5000

Dz(i,j)=5000;

end

elseif 0.400 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 0.500

a= 346.75 ; b= 1.7283 ;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;


if Dz(i,j)>5000

Dz(i,j)=5000;

end

elseif 0.500 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 3.110

a= 453.85 ; b= 2.1166 ;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;


if Dz(i,j)>5000

Dz(i,j)=5000;

end

elseif x(i,j) >= 3.110

a= 453.85 ; b= 2.1166 ;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  


if Dz(i,j)>5000

Dz(i,j)=5000;

end

if x(i,j)<0.20 % x in kilometers

a = 90.673; b = 0.93198;%...stabilitas is B

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end


if Dz(i,j)>5000

Dz(i,j)=5000;

end

elseif 0.21 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 0.40

a = 98.483; b = 0.98332;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b; 


if Dz(i,j)>5000

Dz = 5000;

end

elseif x(i,j)>= 0.40

a = 109.400; b = 1.09710;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

if Dz(i,j)>5000

Dz = 5000;

end



if x(i,j) == all % x in kilometers

a = 61.141; b = 0.91465;%...stabilitas is C

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  


if Dz(i,j)>5000

Dz = 5000;

end





if x(i,j)== 0.30 % x in kilometers

a = 34.459; b = 0.86974;%...stabilitas is D

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end


if 0.31 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 1.00

a = 32.093; b = 0.81066;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end


if 1.01 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 3.00

a = 32.093; b = 0.64403;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end


if 3.01 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 10.00

a = 33.504; b = 0.60486;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end

if 10.01 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 30.00

a = 36.650; b = 0.56589;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end

if x(i,j)>= 30.00

a = 44.053; b =0.51179;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end



if x(i,j) < 0.10 % x in kilometers

a = 24.260; b = 0.83660; %...stabilitas is E  

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b; 

end


if 0.10 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 30.00

a = 23.331; b = 0.81956;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end


if 0.31 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 1.00

a = 21.628; b = 0.75660;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end


if 1.01 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 2.00

a = 21.628; b = 0.63077;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end

if 2.01 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 4.00

a = 22.534; b = 0.57154;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end

if 4.01 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 10.00

a = 24.703; b = 0.50527;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end

if 10.01 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 20.00

a = 26.970; b = 0.46713;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end

if 20.01 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 40.00

a = 35.420; b = 0.37615;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end

if x(i,j) >=40.00

a = 44.053; b = 0.51179;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end


if x(i,j) < 0.20 % x in kilometers

a = 15.209; b = 0.81558;%...stabilitas is F

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end

if 0.21 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 0.70

a = 14.457; b = 0.78407;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b; 

end

if 0.71 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 1.00

a = 13.953; b = 0.68465;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b; 

end

if 1.01 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 2.00

a = 13.953; b = 0.63227;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b; 

end

if 2.01 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 3.00

a = 14.823; b = 0.54503;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end

if 3.01 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 7.00

a = 16.187; b = 0.46490;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end

if 7.01 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 15.00

a = 17.836; b = 0.41507;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end


if 15.01 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 30.00

a = 22.651; b = 0.32681;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end

if 30.01 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 60.00

a = 27.074; b = 0.27436;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end


if x(i,j)>= 60.00

a = 34.219; b = 0.21716;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;

end

end

end


end

end

for i = 1:size(Q,2)

    xx = x - xstack(i);

    yy = y - ystack(i); 

end


    deltah(i,j) = V.*D./u.*1.5 + 2.68.*(10^(-3)).*P.*(Ts-Ta).*D./Ts;

    H = h + deltah;

 c2 = c + Q(i).*e./(4.*pi.*xx.*sqrt(Dy.*Dz)).*exp(-v.*yy.*yy./(4.*Dy.*xx)).*... 

(exp(-v.*(z-H(i)).*(z-H(i)).*e./(4.*Dz.*xx))+exp(-v.*(z+H(i)).*(z+H(i)).*e./(4.*Dz.*xx)))...

.*exp(-lambda.*xx./v);


%----------------------------------output----------------------------------

if gplot

    for i = 10:10:100

        plot (c1(:,i)); hold on;

        plot (c2(:,i)); hold on;

    end

end

if gcont

    figure;

    if gcont > 1

        contourf (x,y,c); colorbar;

    else

        contour (x,y,c); 

    end

end
```

---

Anyone can help me please?!

Comment: Your code example is way to big to see the error. Try reducing the code. If you have less then 30 lines, you can update your question. But I guess it will be a lot more easy to spot the problem yourself once you have done that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I run the code you have posted, I find that the 'c' variable is a single value, while 'x' and 'y' are matrices. So your problem is in the dimensions of the variables you try to plot together.

To debug your code try inserting a breakpoint in the code where the error occurs. Then when you run the code, it will stop at the breakpoint and you can check the values and dimensions of your variables.

Comment: could you explain it detail? because I'm beginner
I've changed the 'c' variable, but i still get error

Comment: You insert a breakpoint by clicking the code line number to the left of the actual code. Then when you run you code, you can inspect the variables to see if their dimensions is as expected. To debug you must have an idea of how the code is supposed to work!  If you don't know what the code is doing, but have just copied it from somewhere, I suggest starting with simple code until you get the hang of Matlab.